# jsPDF image keeps displaying in wrong order on wrong page

Tags: jspdf, html2canvas

I am using jsPDF to create a PDF download.

Below is my code, which works perfectly to display all the bits of info I need so far.

I want everything to display on the PDF in the order I have the code:

- Banner
- Logo
- Job Title
- Main Content

Everything sits exactly where it should except for the Banner.
It keeps displaying below all of the content.

In the output PDF I can see the space at the top where it should sit, but it always goes to the last page of the document, after all other content. On the page it displays, it sits in the top left corner and is the correct width and height, so it is doing that correctly, but is just on the wrong page.

What have I stuffed up here? Or how can i force it to sit on page 1?

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

```
   function demoFromHTML() {

          var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
 var lMargin=20; //left margin in mm
    var rMargin=20; //right margin in mm     
    var pdfInMM=210;  // width of A4 in mm


    var source = document.getElementById('text-7');

// Banner

     html2canvas(jQuery("#top-banner"), {
        useCORS : true,
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
           var banner = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

           doc.addImage(banner, 'PNG', 0, 0, 210, 100);

            console.log(banner);
                   setTimeout(function () {
    doc.save('"<?php echo ( get_the_title() );?>"');
}, 0);  

        }
    })  


// Logo

       var logo = 'data:image/png;base64,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';


       doc.addImage(logo, 'PNG', 10, 100, 50, 18);


// Job title
        doc.setTextColor(0,0,0);
        doc.fromHTML(
            jQuery('.job_listing-title').get(0), // [Refer Exact code tutorial][2]HTML string or DOM elem ref.
            10,    // x coord
            125,    // y coord
             {
                 'width': 190,
             });

// Main content
         doc.fromHTML(
            jQuery('#main').get(0), // [Refer Exact code tutorial][2]HTML string or DOM elem ref.
            10,    // x coord
            135,    // y coord
             {
                 'width': 190,
             });

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After posting, I realised how simple the answer was.

The issue was occurring because I was firing the doc.save inside the html2canvas, prior to the logo, job title or main content. Instead I needed to move all of the other content under the banner, but before the doc.save.

The below now functions correctly and outputs all items in the correct order and positions.

```
  function demoFromHTML() {


          var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
 var lMargin=20; //left margin in mm
    var rMargin=20; //right margin in mm     
    var pdfInMM=210;  // width of A4 in mm


    var source = document.getElementById('text-7');

     html2canvas(jQuery("#top-banner"), {
        useCORS : true,
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
           var banner = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

// Banner

           doc.addImage(banner, 'PNG', 0, 0, 210, 100);

// Logo

             var logo = 'data:image/png;base64,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';


       doc.addImage(logo, 'PNG', 10, 100, 50, 18);

// Job title       

        doc.setTextColor(0,0,0);
        doc.fromHTML(
            jQuery('.job_listing-title').get(0), // [Refer Exact code tutorial][2]HTML string or DOM elem ref.
            10,    // x coord
            125,    // y coord
             {
                 'width': 190,
             });

// Main content

         doc.fromHTML(
            jQuery('#main').get(0), // [Refer Exact code tutorial][2]HTML string or DOM elem ref.
            10,    // x coord
            135,    // y coord
             {
                 'width': 190,
             });



            console.log(banner);
                   setTimeout(function () {
    doc.save('"<?php echo ( get_the_title() );?>"');
}, 0);  

        }
    })  

    }
```